# Powershell NetEventSession

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run the following script, however i keep getting the error below:

Script:

```
param(
  [UInt16]$port=25
)

New-NetEventSession -Name "Capture" -CaptureMode RealtimeLocal -LocalFilePath "C:\Users\5.etl"

Add-NetEventWFPCaptureProvider -SessionName "Capture" -TCPPorts $port

Start-NetEventSession -Name "Capture"
```

and the error I get is:

> ```
> Error: Start-NetEventSession : A general error occurred that is not
> covered by a more specific error code. At
> C:\Users\shaun\Documents\Untitled1.ps1:6 char:1
> + Start-NetEventSession -Name "Capture"
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_NetEventSe...477B5AAB18AF}"):root/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetEventSession) [St     art-NetEventSession], CimException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 1,Start-NetEventSession
> ```

Any thoughts?

I'm new to coding & PowerShell, and I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: You should pretty print (format) your code. That makes it much more likely, that anyone will read it.

Comment: Thanks Xan-Kun Clark-Davis.

Answer (score 0):

TCPPorts expects an array. So i think your param-var should look like this:

```
param(

  [UInt16[]]$Ports

)
```

-TCPPorts []
        Specifies an array of TCP ports. The provider filters for and logs network 
        traffic that matches the ports that this 
        parameter specifies. The provider joins multiple port numbers with logical 
        ORs.

Comment: Thanks KonnerZ, however i still receive the same output.